# SQS message not being sent

Tags: javascript, amazon-sqs

I have a function that adds an item to my dynamo db, and I also would like it to send the item to my sqs queue so I can put it into another lambda function. When I run my code, the data gets put into the db, but not sent to the queue. I don't even get an error.

```
import * as dynamoDbLib from "./libs/dynamodb-lib";
import { success, failure } from "./libs/response-lib";
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const sqs = new AWS.SQS();

export async function main(event, context) {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

  console.log(data);
  var site = "IE"+data.siteCounty+data.siteName;
  var siteIdStripped = site.replace(/[aeiou]/g, '');
  var siteId = siteIdStripped.replace(/ /g,'');
  var siteIdFinal = siteId.toUpperCase();

  const params = {
    "TableName": "sites",
    "Item": {
      userId: event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
      siteId: siteIdFinal,
      ...data,
      createdAt: Date.now()
    }
  };

  const messageParams = {
    MessageBody: params.Item,
    QueueURL: 'https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/106845550704/TranslateText'
  };

  function sendMessage(messageParams) {
    sqs.sendMessage(messageParams, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error: "+err);
      } else {
        console.log("Success: "+data.MessageId);
      }
    });
  }

  try {
    await dynamoDbLib.call("put", params);
    sendMessage(messageParams);
    return success(params.Item);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return failure({ status: false });
  }


}
```

Comment: I would suggest you start by simply trying to send a message to the SQS queue (without all the DynamoDB stuff). Once you get that working, you can try and figure out what is causing the problem. For example, `params.Item` is a dictionary, whereas `MessageBody` is expecting a string, so this could be causing the problem.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have the message being sent, when I run it I now get returned the MessageId. But in my aws console it says there are no messages

Comment: That is indeed interesting! I wonder if you have queues in multiple regions and it is going to the wrong region? Do you have anything consuming messages from the queue? You can use CloudTrail to check the API calls to see what might be happening.